# CopyOnArrayList Concurrent modification

Tags: java

When we run above program, we get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` as soon as the `ArrayList` is modified. It happens because `ArrayList` iterator is fail-fast by design. What it means is that once the iterator is created, if the `ArrayList` is modified, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
public class ConcurrentListExample {

    public void someMethod() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");

        // get the iterator
        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

        //manipulate list while iterating
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String str = it.next();
            System.out.println(str);
            if (str.equals("2")) {
                list.remove("5");
            }
            if (str.equals("3")) {
                list.add("3 found");
            }
            if(str.equals("4")) {
                list.set(1, "4");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if we take `Employee` class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List al = new ArrayList();
        Employee ee = new Employee(1, "anoj");
        Employee ee1 = new Employee(2, "hai");
        al.add(ee);
        al.add(ee1);
        Iterator it = al.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Employee hh = (Employee)it.next();
            if (hh.getName().equals("anoj")) {
                al.remove(0);
                System.out.println(al);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Its correct "You should add or remove an object while iterating.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting? It's hard to see what's going on in this code. In the first block, please decrease the indentation level so that it doesn't march off the right of the screen. And in the second block, please add indentation as appropriate. This will make it easier for people to read your question and provide an answer.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify and print operations simultaneously using iterator.
it support `add()` and `remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fail on the second time because the `iterator` returns `anoj` last.  So `hasNext` returns false and `next` is never called, thus no `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Simply move the addition of `ee1` above `ee` and it will fail

**Note**  This is internal implementation to `ArrayList` as to 1.  Why anoj is returned last and 2. Why `hasNext` doesnt throw CME.

Answer (score 1):

The check for concurrent modification exception gas a flaw that if you remove the second last element of an ArrayList it wont complain but will skip the last entry.

this happens because it checks whether it has iterated size() times before checking the concurrent modification.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct explanation is this extract from th [javadocs of ConcurrentModificationExcetion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for
>   its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only
>   to detect bugs.

Comment: yes i have updated the answer with the link. sorry i should have done it before.